# Service getExtra returns null with started from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a remote service which I pass some extras and. The service can either be started from an activity or from a broadcast receiver. When started from the activity, i pass in extras and an action and I'm able to retrieve them in the service. But when I do the same from the broadcast receiver, calling `getExtra()` or `getAction` both return null.

Here's how it's started from the broadcast receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    intent.setAction("receieverAction");
    intent.putExtra("some_extra", "extra_value");
    context.startService(service);
}
```

Then in the service i call getExtras and getAction() both are null

```
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String action = intent.getAction(); // This is null when started from broadcast receiver
        String extra = intent.getStringExtra("some_extra"); // and so is this
        ...

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

Does this have to do with the broadcastreceiver speicfically or that the service is already started when the receiver calls `startService()`

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says:

> In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from
>   within a BroadcastReceiver.

I guess that problem is in about `starting service` from `broadcastreceiver`.

Comment: I'm not binding to the service from the broadcast receiver, I'm just starting it. The service starts correctly and is running, it's just not getting the action or extras. Basically I'm using the action/extras so the service knows if it was started from the activity or receiver so it can act differently in each case.